# Need help on geolocation API

Tags: geolocation, maps

I need to implement street view, but it seems that google does not have that capability for India. 
I want that The map should be dynamic and the customer should be able to see point of interest near a specified point and within a given radius or zip code.

I need to geocode and reverse geocode

Can somebody share an idea and one quick example of this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get places of interest near by some location, then I would suggest using [HERE PLACES API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places) for that task. The site should also include nice examples for the API. Also its simple REST API, so it would work in any platform really.